# Using prototype to define a getter/setter

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

If I have an application with a bunch of getters and setters, then I think that I need to use closures to keep the value of the setter, don't I?

Here's what I've got so far, but I think these two methods should be returning functions (closures).  I don't think I should be using this.local.result because the two will conflict.

```
myApplication = function(){
    this.local = {};  
};
myApplication.prototype.myFirstMethod = function(){
    if (arguments.length) {
        this.local.result = arguments[0];
    } else {
        return this.local.result;
    } 
};
myApplication.prototype.mySecondMethod = function(){
    if (arguments.length) {
        this.local.result = arguments[0];
    } else {
        return this.local.result;
    } 
};

var app = new myApplication();
app.myFirstMethod(1);
result = app.myFirstMethod();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of using closures is to keep the variable private (not directly accessible from the global scope).

Here is how to use a closure:

```
myApplication.prototype.myFirstMethod = (function () {
    var data = '';
    return function () {
        if (arguments.length) {
            data = arguments[0];
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
})();
```

If you dont need the data to be private, you can simply do this:

```
myApplication.prototype.myFirstMethod = function(){
    if (arguments.length) {
        this.local['firstData'] = arguments[0];
    } else {
        return this.local['firstData'];
    } 
};
```

Comment: But won't the arguments keyword be confused by the "return function()" and think that there are _never_ any arguments?

Comment: No. The returned function acts like any other function, only difference being it has access to the data variable. The closure is returning the function object, not executing it.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'myFirstMethod' of undefined. I don't understand the need for an IIFE here.

Comment: The IIFE creates a new local-scope, which means variables set within it, are not accessible in the global scope. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/